# Remove whitespace between html attributes

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to remove the white space/ blank characters inside HTML attributes:

Initial

```
<p style="font-size: 1.5em; color: navy;">
 Text With Spaces
<p style="font-size: 1.2em; color: navy;">
```

Desired

```
<p style="font-size:1.5em;color:navy;">
 Text with spaces
<p style="font-size:1.2em;color:navy;">
```

First I tried to removed all the whitespaces by using preg_replace then doing a find and replace to insert back the  however that removed all spaces from the document

```
$cont = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $original);
$cont2 = str_replace('<p', "<p ", $cont2);
```

Incorrect

```
<p style="font-size:1.5em;color:navy;">
 Textwithspaces
<p style="font-size:1.5em;color:navy;">
```

Comment: You can do a web search for "minify" that will help you with this as well.

Comment: Are you trying to make us write your regex for you?

Comment: RegEx is not the right tool for this. Minify the code before putting it into production if you really care that much.

Comment: @TylerH Hey, Trying Minify - however it seems to be only remove whitespaces outside of the tags. ie.) In my example - it didn't remove the space between "font-size:" & "1.2em"

Comment: @RedRory Hmm, maybe you will just have to find a specific minify tool that will do this, since having spaces like that is considered valid, most tools don't remove it, I guess. Maybe a more specific web search "minify tool that removes spaces within tags" or something.

Comment: If you want do this with regex, the first step is to use DOMDocument and XPath to isolate values of style attributes (see the php doc or use a search engine:`php xpath get attribute value` , it is a basic step). All you need after, is to build a regex pattern to remove unwanted spaces but only in a css context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes it a little tricky in that you want to remove any spaces, except the one immediately after the tag name, but it certainly can be done.

```
$string = '<p style="font-size: 1.5em; color: navy;">
 Text With Spaces
<p style="font-size: 1.2em; color: navy;"> ';

$string = preg_replace_callback('~<([A-Z0-9]+) \K(.*?)>~i', function($m) {$replacement = preg_replace('~\s*~', '', $m[0]); return $replacement;}, $string);

print $string;
```

What I'm doing here is looking for an opening HTML bracket `<`, followed by a tag name, followed by a space.  For the tag name, I'm using a character class `[]` that allows letters `A-Z` and numbers `0-9`.  It must contain at least one of those characters `+`, but may contain more than that ... all the way up until it hits a space.  Then I'm telling the REGEX to start remembering our matches from this point forward `\K` and look for any character `.` as many times as it can find it `*`, all the way up until it hits the next thing in our REGEX `?`.  In this case, the next thing in our REGEX is a closing HTML bracket `>`.

Then I'm using `preg_replace_callback` to evaluate each match that it finds.  For each match, it looks for any number of spaces `\s*` and replaces them with nothing.

This will give you what you are asking for:

```
<p style="font-size:1.5em;color:navy;">
  Text With Spaces
<p style="font-size:1.2em;color:navy;">
```

However, it will also have some other side effects.  Take, for example, a string like this:

```
$string = '<p style="font-size: 1.5em; color: navy;"><a href="http://www.google.com" style="color: orange;">Google Website</a>
 Text With Spaces
<p style="font-size: 1.2em; color: navy;"> <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif" width=100 height=100>';
```

Using the above regular expression will give you results like this:

```
<p style="font-size:1.5em;color:navy;"><a href="http://www.google.com"style="color:orange;">Google Website</a>
 Text With Spaces
<p style="font-size:1.2em;color:navy;"> <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif"width=100height=100>
```

To get around that, you'd have to make a couple of matches & replaces, because you'd need to look for quotes/ticks around items, however, those items would need to be inside HTML tags.  You can't do something like this:

```
<.*?"(.*?)".*?>
```

because it wouldn't match things like `"http://www.google.com" style="color:orange;"` where you have multiple sets of quotes inside the HTML tag.  To work around this, I first pulled out the tags and then once I had those, pulled out the content between each set of quotes for evaluation.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('~<(.*?)>~i', 

    function($m) {

        $return_var = preg_replace_callback('~\'|".*?\'|"~', function ($r) {$v = preg_replace('~\s*~', '', $r[0]); return $v;}, $m[0]);
        return $return_var;
    }, 

    $string);

print $string;
```

This is basically two `preg_replace_callbacks` shoved into one statement.  The first tells the function to operate on any tags.  The second one tells the functions to operate on anything inside of quotes/ticks within those HTML tags.

[Here is a demo so you can compare the different options](http://ideone.com/Mpqhd3)